# Using phy_rotation to follow the mouse [Gamemaker]

Tags: game-maker

My `oPlayer` object (a physics object in Gamemaker) uses the following code to follow the mouse:

```
phy_rotation = point_direction(phy_position_x,phy_position_y,mouse_x,mouse_y)
direction = phy_rotation - 180
image_angle = direction
```

However, though it does rotate in reaction to mouse movement, the `oPlayer` object's `image_angle` is always the opposite of the `point_direction` to the mouse!

I've tried to set it to

point_direction = (phy_position_x,phy_position_y,mouse_x,mouse_y) - 180

but to no avail.

Any help with getting **the `oPlayer` object to point in the direction between itself and the mouse's position** would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this now, for anybody looking for a similar solution.

Rather than adding `-180` to the `point_direction`, you must instead make it a *negative* value, thus:

```
phy_rotation = -point_direction(phy_position_x,phy_position_y,mouse_x,mouse_y)
```

With this code, the physics-enabled object will always face towards the mouse position. This is because `phy_rotation` operates in the **opposite** direction from the `direction` value in non-physics Gamemaker objects.